# Custom generated Identity column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I read the documentation for Identity columns in Oracle as detailed here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/19.1/java-driver-table/creating-tables-identity-column.html

The documentation mentions that the values that get inserted by the sequence generator into the identity column are integers. This can be found here
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/19.1/java-driver-table/sequence-generator-attributes.html

Now, my question is this: Is there a way to have custom values generated for the identity column?
Other than integer values. Say, a string like 'ID001', 'ID002' etc?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You are reading the wrong manual. It's not about the Oracle relational database. It's the manual for the JDBC driver of the Oracle **NoSQL**

Comment: ... or the `tag` is wrong;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but you'll have to do something about it (i.e. write some code - a trigger). Here's an example.

Sample table; its ID column should be auto-generated:

```
SQL> create table test (id varchar2(10), name varchar2(10));

Table created.
```

A sequence, which will be used in a trigger:

```
SQL> create sequence seq_test;

Sequence created.
```

Trigger is rather simple; it concatenates `ID` with a sequence number, left-padded with zeroes up to 3 characters in length (as your example says so):

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_test
  2    before insert on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.id := 'ID' || lpad(seq_test.nextval, 3, '0');
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into test (name) values ('Little');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test (name)
  2    select 'Foot'      from dual union all
  3    select 'Equalizer' from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from test order by id;

ID         NAME
---------- ----------
ID001      Little
ID002      Foot
ID003      Equalizer

SQL>
```

---

P.S. Link you posted isn't related to "traditional" Oracle database; check e.g. [CREATE TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402) documentation, it contains info about identity columns. Your link is related to NoSQL database.

Comment: This helps @Littlefoot. Thank you. Sorry, I wrongly allocated the tag :)

Answer (score 2):

*First* think why should you  use  strings as a *primary key*.

Do you see some advantage? (Other than using **more** storage?)

*Secondly* with your key such as `ID001` consider what should happen if you have more than 1000 rows...

One explanation is that you are looking for some *user readable identification* of the row. This can be provided using the *standard [IDENTITY](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6)* plus an additional [*virtual column*](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1)

**Example**

```
create table MY_TABLE (
ID number(19,0) generated as identity, 
ID_DESC varchar2(255 char) generated always as ('ID'||ID) virtual,
col int,
primary key (ID))
;

insert into my_table(col)
select rownum from dual connect by level <= 3;


select id, id_desc from  my_table order by id;

        ID ID_DESC
---------- ---------        
         1 ID1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
         2 ID2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
         3 ID3
```

Comment: Thank you MarmiteBomber. This gives another good perspective.
The answer given by @Littlefoot explains what I wanted. I will change the tag. Sorry for the confusion.